# Linux shell bash script if condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell, conditional-statements

When I run this on my server it works.

```
if [[ "${Month}" -gt 12 ]] || [[ "${Day}" -gt 31 ]] || [[ "${Month}" -lt 0 ]] || [[ "${Day}" -lt 0 ]] || [[ "${Year}" -lt 0 ]] || [[ "${Year}" -gt 2050 ]]; then
    echo "Please enter Valid date choice."       
    exit 1
fi
```

But when my customer runs in their environment it generates a syntax error.

```
bash-4.1$ ./port_generator.sh "/opt/device/server/scripts/Results" "2017-01-29"
./port_generator.sh: line 31: syntax error near unexpected token `||'
./port_generator.sh: line 31: `|| [[ "${Year}" -lt 0 ]] || [[ "${Year}" -gt 2050 ]]; then'
```

Release on server success is : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
Release on server fail is : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago)

Comment: What's the `shebang` line?

Comment: What is the exact command that you are using to run the script? What command is the customer using? It looks like the customer is using bash to run it, while you are using sh, or vice-versa.

Comment: I'm obliged to believe that the actual code being run is not in fact an exact match for the code generating the bug. We need an actual reproducer -- a [mcve] -- to make any useful headway here.

Comment: The successfull command : [root@testServ45-149 mytest]# ./port_generator.sh  |||  Fail server command  : bash-4.1$ ./port_generator.sh

Comment: @ivbtar, I don't mean the invocation, I mean the command run *by the script*, in a tested form known to reproduce the problem exactly as-given. What's given here in the question does *not*, on its own, produce the problem at hand.

Comment: @ivbtar, ...that said, what `./port_generator.sh` will invoke as an interpreter (ie. `/bin/bash` vs `/bin/sh`) depends on the shebang -- the first line -- which isn't specified here, so that's another pertinent and missing detail.

Comment: Year=`echo ${DATE_ARG} | cut -d"-" -f1`

Comment: First line : #!/bin/bash

Comment: Could you please post the full script so we can understand what is going on? If you can't post the full script, at least provide us all the information we need!

Comment: Can you test with a small script, setting Day, Month and Year. Next the if-statement. Sometimes an error is made on a previous line and you get an error on a correct line.

Comment: @ivbtar: I would for the save side output the value of $BASH_VERSION just before the offending statement, but I don't think the reason is a different version of the bash. What is strange is, that it complains about just one `]] ||` sequence in the middle of the statement (and not about, say, the first one being encountered). Maybe the file at your customer's side has - for what ever reason - some non-printable character embedded? Have a look at the file (after installation at the customer's side) with some hexdump utiliy.

Comment: @ivbtar: And as a pragmatic approach (without solving the riddle): I would rewrite the statement to `if (( Month > 12 || Day > 31 || ..... || Year > 2050))`, which is IMO easier to read.

Answer (score -1):

Your script should have a shebang line at the top: `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. But that's not the problem. If it were, the error would point to the first `||`, not the fourth one.

Do you have the `if` statement on two separate lines in your actual script? This would generate the message you're seeing:

```
if [[ "${Month}" -gt 12 ]] || [[ "${Day}" -gt 31 ]] || [[ "${Month}" -lt 0 ]] || [[ "${Day}" -lt 0 ]]
|| [[ "${Year}" -lt 0 ]] || [[ "${Year}" -gt 2050 ]]; then
```

If that's what you did, don't. Or if you do want the line split up, end the first line with `||` so that the parser knows the command isn't finished.

```
if [[ "${Month}" -gt 12 ]] || [[ "${Day}" -gt 31 ]] || [[ "${Month}" -lt 0 ]] || [[ "${Day}" -lt 0 ]] ||
   [[ "${Year}" -lt 0 ]] || [[ "${Year}" -gt 2050 ]]; then
```

Comment: It is in one line not seperated

Comment: it has :  #!/bin/bash

Answer (score -1):

Does your script have a shebang? What shell is the customer running the script in? Do you use the same shell?

```
netikras@netikras-xps ~ $ bash
netikras@netikras-xps ~ $ if [[ 3 -gt 1 ]]; then echo OK; fi
OK
netikras@netikras-xps ~ $ csh
% if [[ 3 -gt 1 ]]; then echo OK; fi
[[: No match.
% exit
```

Not all shells have the same syntax. Make sure you and your client are using the same shell. Or update the answer with more info